# Remove/delete object from array in Ruby based on attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array

`result = [{:cluster=>[0, 4], :id=>1, :units=>346, :num1=>0.161930681e7, :num2=>0.14223512616e9, "description"=>"Foo"}, { ...`

And I want to take out any objects with number of units equal to 0. Looking for something similar to `array.splice()` but for ***Ruby***
What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) method to return the array without objects whose `:units` equals `0`:

```
result.reject { |hash| hash[:units] == 0 }
```

There's also `#reject!` and [`#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if), which can be used in the same way as above *but both modify the array in place*.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result using [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method implemented on the `Array` class:

`result.select { |el| el[:units] == 0 }`

Comment: This seems to be how to create a new array with the objects with units = 0

Comment: Ah, I see what you wanted. You wanted to get rid of the objects with units == 0, not an array of those objects.You are right.